# Is Gargantua a black hole or a wormhole?

Tags: interstellar

I will write the events in sequence but in a brief manner. Later on questions will be asked. Correct me if I'm wrong anywhere.

First of all Cooper and his crew go through a wormhole that is near Saturn into another system (Gargantua's system) where they go to Miller's and Mann's planet and after an encounter with Dr.Mann, and after docking with Endurance CASE warns Cooper that Endurance is slipping towards Gargantua's pull. Then a lot happens and Cooper and TARS end up in a tesseract and after relaying the data

1. Is it that "they" the 5th dimensional beings (after the job is done) safely scoop Cooper out of Gargantua (the tesseract actually; which is not in Gargantua's singularity but in the 5D box) and send him back in that 5D box through the extra dimensions back to our solar system through the SAME wormhole through which he came in first to visit Miller’s and Mann’s planet which is also near Saturn?
2. If it is that then why does [this timeline](https://www.behance.net/gallery/21179181/Interstellar-Timeline) show as if Gargantua was used as a wormhole to transport him back to our universe? I mean Gargantua is a black hole and so the picture is misleading right? It also shows the same structure of Gargantua on below left of Cooper station in our universe as it was in the other system (Gargantua's system), but there is ONLY ONE wormhole which has no resemblance with Gargantua’s structure. Am I right?

   [image]
3. See the image, you will find in the poster infographic below that they have written wormhole (which they use to go to Gargantua's system) as a black hole! That is wrong, am I right?

So **was the wormhole they came through a "normal" wormhole or actually a black hole? And is Gargantua a wormhole or a black hole?** What explains the contradictions between this infographic and how I understood the story, **did I misunderstand anything or is this picture just inaccurate?**

Comment: Ok, I gave it a second read and tried to crystallize a core question out of your many elaborations which I added at the end. I hope this reflects what you want to ask. Otherwise, feel free to roll the edit back to its previous version and elaborate yourself what you want to know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Yes, you are right, Gargantua is a black hole.

You described the story of the movie quite correctly and it is actually that **timeline image you linked that is wrong** in some parts and a little inaccurate in other parts.

1. Yes, **[after falling into Gargantua Cooper lands in the tesseract](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/27315/49)**, which is something of a 4-dimensional represenation of the "Bulk Beings'" 5-dimensional universe, placed there for him by them. And **[through this thing they send him back](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/27199/49)** to Saturn at the end. It is not entirely clear how *exactly* they send him back from there. While his "hand shake" with Amelia suggest that the wormhole is involved somehow, it is not clear and that hand shake might as well have happened in some other weird spacetime way.
2. You are totally right, **[Gargantua is a black hole](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/27252/49), *not* a wormhole** and neither was Gargantua directly visible from Cooper Station's side of the wormhole (other than maybe indirectly *through* the wormhole). The **graph is a little inaccurate** there when it depicts the black hole both as a wormhole and with one end on the Saturn side. I would think this was just artistically chosen this way to **convey that it is the black hole (or more exactly, the tesseract in there) that is used to transport Cooper back** to Staturn, however that actual transport really works.
3. Yes, you are right. This is just a plain and clear error in the image. They definitely **mean the wormhole there** (as it's also drawn that way), which is something completely different from a black hole.

---

On a related note, I for myself prefer the [second timeline listed here](http://sploid.gizmodo.com/interstellar-explained-in-one-timeline-warning-spoile-1656588261) (which also lists the one you got), as it is much more detailed and accurate. It has (what I think to be) a few *little* mistakes and misunderstandings too, but is overall much more accurate to the timeline and events of the film:

[image]

Comment: Yeah - the handshake (being in the past) must be something to do with gravity and the tesseract, since the movie is at pains to say that you physically cannot go back in time.  But he does end up back in the Saturn area, so maybe the spacetime constructs made in Gargantua and the wormhole and related.

Comment: @iandotkelly Well, I think the hand shake is one of the most scientifically disputed things about the (otherwise quite scientifically sound) film and I would attribute that more into the area of story-telling and artistic license in the first place.

Comment: Yes, the timeline indeed is the problem (I did not make it). The timeline was obtained from the internet, and upon looking I knew the timeline was very wrong and it had me in confusion (I knew the right concept of movie though; as I explained it in my questions). You sorted it out and I am very grateful (I mean you were very good at understanding and interpreting my questions). Just one last thing you said:"...however that actual transport really works." In your answer to my 2 question. What exactly did you meant in the context??? All of the questions have been  answered otherwise...

Comment: @FlightMuj I just mean, that we don't really know how exactly the transport of Cooper back to Saturn actually worked. It's not explained much in the film and the whole hand-shake between him and Amelia makes it a little confusing. All we know is, that the "bulk beings" transported Cooper back to Saturn through the tesseract *somehow*.

Comment: Oh!!! I get it...

Answer (score 5):

#### TL;DR The Bulk Beings are so technologically advanced that they could manipulate the Black Hole and Worm Holes like child's play, creating new or modifying them to save Cooper.

According to [this Space.com infographic](http://www.space.com/images/i/000/043/506/original/interstellar-wormhole-travel-141107b-02.jpg?1415387135) on [this Space.com article](http://www.space.com/27701-interstellar-movie-science-black-holes.html), sourced from various books, including the accompanying science guide to the movie "The Science of Interstellar" by the movie's physics consultant Kip Thorne:

[image]

***A wormhole is nothing but an artificially connected set of black holes, which themselves are the creation of massive gravitational forces.***

The Bulk Beings, future humans capable of surviving in 5th dimensional space, are shown to have control over gravity in our 3rd dimensional space. To wit, ***they created the wormhole between Saturn and the Gargantua system***. They manipulated time and space so that Cooper could manipulate gravity across time. They plucked Cooper out of a supermassive black hole into a construct, the tesseract, 4th dimensional space.

### So there is two easy to consider methods they saved Cooper.

1. They plucked him out of the black hole Gargantua, and send him back through the Saturn wormhole, by manipulating gravity. Think of Cooper becoming a surfer in a pocket of space/air that is his surfboard. Manipulated Gravity and normal space being the wave.
2. Since they are capable of engineering a 1.25 mile wide, 10 billion light year long wormhole, which the above infographic shows is the artificial manipulation of black holes, ***The Bulk Beings manipulated Gargantua to connect to the Saturn Wormhole and/or a new singularity long enough to drop Cooper off.***

To explain the Future Cooper touching Past Brand, ***The Bulk Beings pulled Cooper and TARS at some point after they pass the event horizon and TARS gets the Quantum Data they need, and before they reach the end of the singularity to their spaghetti deaths.*** Frankly, Cooper and TARS shouldn't have been able to enter the Event Horizon without dying unless the Bulk Beings were protecting them from the Gravity ***THE ENTIRE TIME***.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more to adress the actual question a little more? Or is this only intended to adress subpart (1) of the question's context elaborations? In this case you might rather want to transfer the answer to a question that more directly answers for these explanations, like [this one](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/27199/49).

Comment: @Napoleon the third paragraph answers the science question of what the black hole and worm hole are. The rest answers the real question of plot.